# Understanding Spark Sessions and Clusters, especially in k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm trying to wrap my head around how my Spark setup is "supposed to work".

I can successfully submit spark jobs, I can run them distributed using our private k8s cluster and I can even have interactive distributed sessions thanks to jupyter enterprise gateway. However, I am still very unsure if I am doing things correctly.

If I just use `spark submit` (no matter if locally, with `--master k8s://...` or as part of my enterprise gateway to spawn kernels that are spark drivers), I get a driver process and executors that communicate with each other. I can also access the spark UI on port 4040 (when in k8s after a `kubectl port-forward`).

However, once my job (or interactive session) is complete, everything is gone. I can use SparkSQL and create tables but likewise, they're gone. As far as I understand, I can also deploy a hive metastore to persist these, even though I have run into some problems here. However, I think this is best address in the separate question.

I can also persist my work by simply writing dataframes to parquet files. That also allows collaboration. In principle, it seems possible to do everything I need. Still, it feels off:

1. to only access the spark UI while a session is running and to create port-forwards to do so.
2. to be able to create tables and then go `spark.catalog.listTables()` (I have even created them in an s3 bucket via `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` set to `s3a://...`) only for it to be lost after the session. I mean, the parquet files are still in s3, but the next session with that warehouse.dir will show an an empty lsit of tables again.

Is this already a desirable situation? Or should I somehow have a running cluster like I have seen from Databricks demos or non-k8s spark deployments? I feel like I should have, but if I follow the official documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html), I always end up in my situation